# Meaning of "candy rippy size"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does "candy rippy size" mean? If I heard it correctly.

The phrase comes from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NZYPcdj_wn4 00:38s - 00:40s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to listen to this clip several times to understand it (native speaker).  I am not certain I have the interpretation correct as it is very hard to hear.

I *think* the commentator says "she's uh, Cathy Ribgy's size".  According to wikipedia Cathy Rigby is a famous gymast prominent in that era (1972).  This interpretation makes sense as they are discussing the fact that the move has not been done before.  The reply would probably confirm this but unfortunately the clip ends at this point.